# (VB.NET) Webbrowser contains certain text?

Tags: vb.net, text, browser, contains

I'm afraid I'm in need of help today!

I have this code:

```
If WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Contains("next") Then
                Label3.Text = "xxxx"
            End If
```

And when the "next" is actually on the page, nothing happens.

I also tried

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("next")
```

But it also doesn't work. What should I do now ;(

Comment: Are you sure that the page is completely loaded? Do you rely on the DocumentCompleted event?

Answer (score -1):

Well you can try this:

```
    'On the form_load event:
If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementid").InnerText=Label3.Text
End If
```

---

If you want a text on all the WebBrowser, I don't know how to do this, but you can do a Div with 100% width and height, and Id: elementid, and it's all. ;)

Comment: thanks! but I don't think I explained well. The label is just something I put, it could be anything else like msgbox("smth here"). the problem is that I cant find the element in the page!

Comment: You have to create a HTML file and navigate it, are you doing this?